# ScrollViewer Content size change then ScrollToOffset not working

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, scrollview

I am using a scrollviewer to display an Image within it.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1" Height="500" Width="500" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0" >
    <Image x:Name="img1" Width="100" Source="/MyApp;component/Images/Test.jpg" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

But when I re-size the image in code, and immediately use the ***scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset()*** (to reposition the image) it does not work :

```
img1.Width = 1000;
scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(500);
```

I verified the ***ScrollableWidth*** property after the `img1.Width = 1000` indeed it is not updated yet. So I used the ***UpdateLayout()*** right after I resize the image, great now the ***ScrollableWidth*** is updated :

```
img1.Width = 1000;
scrollViewer1.UpdateLayout();
scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(500);
```

but the ***ScrollToHorizontalOffset*** is still not working. If I do it afterwards, on another user button click it works though. :/

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Nevermind... My error, the example above works. In my project I was basing the ScrollToHorizontalOffset on the img1.ActualWidth which was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... My error, the example above works. In my project I was basing the `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` on the `img1.ActualWidth` which was not updated.

Sorry :/